# How to sort strings in Typescript if subtraction cannot be performed on two strings?

Tags: typescript

In JS it's pretty easy:

```
var versions = ["1.12", "1.1", "1.25", "1.5", "1.3", "1.2"];
var sorted = versions.sort(function (version1, version2) {
    return version2 - version1;
});
console.log(sorted);

// -> [ '1.5', '1.3', '1.25', '1.2', '1.12', '1.1' ]
```

However, when I try to do this in Typescript:

```
const versions: string[] = ["1.12", "1.1", "1.25", "1.5", "1.3", "1.2"];

const sorted = versions.sort((version1: string, version2: string) => {
  return version2 - version1;
})

// -> error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

If I use `parseInt`, or do some kind of `number` conversion, the results are not what I want:

```
const versions: string[] = ["1.12", "1.1", "1.25", "1.5", "1.3", "1.2"];

const sorted = versions.sort((version1: string, version2: string) => {
  return parseInt(version2) - parseInt(version1);
})

console.log(sorted)

// -> [ '1.12', '1.1', '1.25', '1.5', '1.3', '1.2' ]
```

How do I sort this?

Thank you!

Comment: Typescripts complains here because treating strings as numbers without explicit conversion is ill advised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `options`.

```js
const versions: string[] = ["1.12", "1.1", "1.25", "1.5", "1.3", "1.2"];

versions.sort((version1: string, version2: string) => {
  return version1.localeCompare(version2, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
})

console.log(versions);
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I wrote the question wrongly, the desired outcome is "1.25" should come before "1.5", because 1.25 is version 1, sub-version 25, and 1.5 is version 1, sub-version 5. Any quick tips for that?

Comment: do you have some more dots in the strings??

Comment: Just the one dot

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat):

```js
const versions: string[] = ["1.12", "1.1", "1.25", "1.5", "1.3", "1.2"];

const sorted = versions.sort((version1: string, version2: string) => {
  return parseFloat(version2) - parseFloat(version1);
});

// -> ["1.5", "1.3", "1.25", "1.2", "1.12", "1.1"]
```

or the [`unary plus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator:

```js
const sorted = versions.sort((version1: string, version2: string) => {
  return +version2 - +version1;
});

// -> ["1.5", "1.3", "1.25", "1.2", "1.12", "1.1"]
```